# Powershell Core and Powershell Modules

Tags: powershell, .net-core, powershell-5.0, powershell-core, powershell-module

I have a need to create a Module that can Run in Powershell 7 and use commandlets from Powershell 5.

I want to save this module as an artifact and publish in AzureDevOps Artifacts.

The Module is for auditing cross platform system information. The problem is that some of the cmdlets are Windows platform specific such as `Get-WindowsFeature`. I also want to use PowerShell Core functions such as Azure Cosmos communication cmdlets.

How do I load functions only on certain platforms?

Do you need to write something in C# to achieve this, or nest a module for a specific platform in my main module?

Comment: `Get-WindowsFeature` ships _with Windows_ - so you won't be able to use it on machines that don't have it, unfortunately

Comment: I get that. But Lets say I only have one Function that uses that. Can I make that specific function only run on PS5.1 windows hosts?

Comment: Sure, do something like `if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt ([version]'6.0')){Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-WindowsOnlyStuff`} in your root module

Answer (score 0):

The comments mention correctly you can wrap up a command with a version check.
That's a great option for a small use command.
I'd recommend as a better module design to just have two modules, one for each platform.
This would allow you to better seperate your work, and not rely on many embedded logic steps that conditionally run actions on different platforms. To me this is just cleaner.

As you get started on modules, I'd highly recommend you use a template to bootstrap your project. I've found that it saves a lot of time, and sets me up for best practices.

My personal favorite is [PSModuleDevelopment](https://psframework.org/) which you can use like this:

```bsh
Install-Module PSModuleDevelopment -Scope CurrentUser
```

```bsh
Get-Help 'Invoke-PSMDTemplate'
```

This is very similar to the loading structure some very mature projects like dbatools and PSFramework use. If you use this, you benefit primarily from:

- Being able to seperate all your functions into their own files and load them easily
- Some nice enhancements to preload configurations in your module
- Pester test template included

I stopped trying to write my own module structure and just leveraged a development module like this, and it's been very helpful for me.

Good luck!